# Edit bytes at particular offsets in stream

Tags: bash, perl, awk

Within an awk program, I call some commands which produce a set of binary strings, all run together.

Within each string:

- the byte at offset 0x04 is a type code
- the four bytes starting at offset 0x09 is the (little endian) length of the string.

If the type code is 0x20, I want to change it to 0x1E.

Example:

The first few bytes of the first string are:

```
4a d8 64 54 13 01 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00
```

From offset 0x04, we see the type code is 0x13, so do nothing.

From offset 0x09, we see the length is 2d 00 00 00. Advance that far from the beginning of this string, to find the start of the next string.

The next string starts:

```
4a d8 64 54 20 01 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00
```

From offset 0x04, we see the type code is 0x20. Change it to 0x1E.

From offset 0x09, we see the length is 2c 00 00 00. Advance that far from the beginning of this string, to find the start of the next string (or EOF).

What utility is best for this?

Comment: I think this is not a task for [tag:awk]. A [tag:perl] is more adequate for this (see: `pack()`, `unpack()`).

Comment: can you parse the data so it appears as your example? Then you can use `if ($4 == "20") ... ` type tests. ? But, `perl` seems like it will be better when then inevitable enhancements are needed, if you can afford the learning curve. Good luck.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. If the offset is little endian, then if the bytes follows as '2d' '00' '00' '00' towards the higher memory addresses then its value is 0x2d, not 0x2d000000.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a solution in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). I assume that the size does not includes the 13 byte header. It is not fully fledged, but works. It is a kind of workbench model. It creates some data in the memory and then it modifies.

So the first part just creates the in-memory data according to the headers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Glues binary strings -> not needed $a.$b works properly
#sub glue(@) { pack "W*", map { unpack("W*", $_) } @_; }

# Creates a <header:null data> record
sub pck(@) {
  my $h = pack "(H[2])*", @_;
  # If it is big-endian use N instead of V!!!
  # It has to be unpacked to get the 32 bit data size
  my @u = unpack "C5V2", $h;
  my $b = pack "x$u[6]"; # put a lot of NULL bytes

  $h.$b;
}

my @h1=qw(4a d8 64 54 13 01 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00);
my @h2=qw(4a d8 64 54 20 01 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00);
my $d1 = pck @h1;
my $d2 = pck @h2;
my $d = $d1.$d2;
```

Now `$d` contains two records: `<header1><zero data1><header2><zero data2>`. Now we can dump the data:

```
sub dumpbin(@) {
  open my $fh, "|od -t x1" or die;
  binmode $fh;
  print $fh @_;
  close $fh;
}

dumpbin($d);
```

Output:

```
0000000 4a d8 64 54 13 01 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4a d8 64 54 20 01
0000100 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000120 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000160 00 00 00
0000163
```

Now the in-memory data can be parsed and modified, if needed. The header is dumped. The offset is printed in octal to be conform to the output of `od`.

```
print "=====\n";
for (my $offs=0; $offs<length($d);) {
  # Unpack header
  my @h = unpack "C5V2", substr($d, $offs, 13);
  # Checks if the header type is 0x20 and modifies it
  if ($h[4] eq 0x20) { substr($d, $offs + 4, 1) = pack "W", 0x1e;}
  printf "%07o HDR: %s%s\n", $offs, join(" ", map {sprintf "%x", $_} @h),
    $h[4] eq 0x20 ? " *" : "";
  $offs += 13 + $h[6];
}
print "=====\n";
```

Output: (modified line marked with '*')

```
=====
0000000 HDR: 4a d8 64 54 13 1 2d
0000072 HDR: 4a d8 64 54 20 1 2c *
=====
```

If we dump the result it can be seen that the data has been changed properly:

```
dumpbin($d);
```

Output:

```
0000000 4a d8 64 54 13 01 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4a d8 64 54 1e 01
0000100 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000120 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000160 00 00 00
0000163
```

It can be seen that the data is modified.

If the input file is big, then some more code is needed to read data in chunks, modify and write back.

I hope this helps!